# Spring JPA - Joining non-persistent fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot Web with JPA, in order to develop an event planning application.
currently, I am working on a public user profile feature, and I need help in designing it, since I am not sure about the optimal way to join non-persistent fields.

The User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "profile_picture")
    private String profilePicture;

    @Column(name = "facebook_token")
    private String facebookToken;

    other fields, method, and private data...
}
```

The UserProfile class:

```
public class UserProfile {

    private final String name;
    private final String email;
    private final String profilePicture;

    ...
}
```

The Guest class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "guests")
public class Guest extends BaseEntity {


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    private Event event;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "is_attending")
    private boolean isAttending;
}
```

What would be the best way to hold the `UserProfile` class in the `Guest` class, considering the fact that the `UserProfile` is a reduction of the `User` class, and it is non-persistent?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Embedded class to hold `UserProfile` in the `Guest` class, but it will be presistent.If you want all attribute of `UserProfile` is non-persistent, you have to add `@Transient` to each attribute of it.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have a non-entity as a relation in JPA because JPA does not know about UserProfile.

One solution could be to have UserProfile as the base class of User and then mapp UserProfile and User with @Inheritence.

Then you can have persistent relationship between Guest and UserProfile

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out why you would ever need to do this honestly. 
Anyhow you would just do the following, but this is a bad practice as you are putting a DTO inside an Entity instead of the opposite:

```
@Transient UserProfile userProfile;
```

Why not just lazily join Guest with User? Or use inheritance from UserProfile by Guest and User as mentioned by others.

Another option is to simply make UserProfile a read-only view that only fetches the desired columns from User.